# What does this もまた mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between も and また?

Context: 山田もまたパーティーに 来ます。

So, も means "too" and the one meaning of また is also "too". What's the difference between these two words and why they were used together in that sentence?

Comment: Maybe また is simply for emphasiz here? Only a guess, don't take too seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is technically ambiguous; また can mean either "also" or "again" here. Assuming the meaning of "again" is not intended, もまた is a literary, emphatic and/or dramatic way of saying "also".

For example, one can say:

- 彼もまた人間なのです。
  He too is a human being.
- それもまた人生だ。
  That's also (a form of) life.
  <sub>(i.e., People's lives are varied.)</sub>

もまた is not redundant at all if used this way.

However, I can feel nothing dramatic or didactic in 山田もまたパーティーに来ます, so this もまた looks a little awkward to me. Maybe the speaker had a good reason to emphasize the "(not only someone but) also" part, or maybe this また just means "again".

Answer (score 0):

In this context も means "as well", it's an addition to a list.

On this other hand, また means "again", it indicates a repetition.

Comment: That sentence is translated like "Yamada will come to the party too". また is not translated as "again" here. Or, maybe, this translation is wrong (I picked it from Jisho.org)?

Comment: It seems to me that また was forgotten in this translation, which would make the translation inaccurate.